# program created on visual studio with local database runs on one pc but not on another

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Any help is great. I created a program in vb.net ultimate 2010 with a local database ".mdf" without using databinding source. This is what I have..

```
Dim cnn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Gomez Rest\Gomez Rest\GomezDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim query As String = Nothing
```

It runs great on the PC that I have created the program and tried it on another, like my laptop and another PC, it runs well without glitch. But when I run it on some other machine, even it it has the same specs and O.S. and on some that has different O.S. but same frameworks, it gives me an error on the sql part. Like so..
"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Gomez Rest\Gomez Rest\GomezDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or the specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC Share...

Sometimes it would generate an error talking about an instance of the sql server or something to that effect. Some PC doesn't have SQL Server so I think it is only natural that it wouldn't have an instance of it.

When I copy and paste it onto another machine I place it inside C:

Comment: Do you have a SQL Service running on other PC ?

Answer (score 0):

There can be Multiple Reasons for connection Failure while doing This :

1. **Wrong Server Name** : In your code, you are using **.\SQLEXPRESS** which indicates the server name as localhost. For you that won't be a problem as your database and application are on same machine.
2. **Wrong DB File Path** : Second Parameter of ConnectionString is Database Name which in your case `AttachDbFileName` attribute. While using this, make your path to the `.mdf`file is correct. ( This is your possible answer by the way )
3. **User Rights** : If you are working in windows 7 or later, UAC might affect access to files on System Drive. If you are usig C:\ drive, make sure to run your application with **Administrative Privileges**

Comment: Do you mean, instead of "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Gomez Rest\Gomez Rest\GomezDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
I must change it to - ("Data Source=AttachDbFilename=C:\Gomez Rest\Gomez Rest\GomezDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True") ... How do I do that since the folder that will be on the end user's machine will just be the bin folder(executables) and the database? There wont be any codes there to change anymore.

Comment: The end user's machine is XP. If I use another machine that has vb.net installed, what I do is I just copy the whole project and open it on the machine's vb then open its .mdf file on the server explorer and everything works fine again. But what if I want to install it on a machine that has no vb.net?

Comment: Your First Comment's answer : No, your connection string is fine. Just put <PCNAME>\SQLEXPRESS and check .mdf file path. Run the file with Administrative privileges as well.

Comment: Do you have SQL Server instance installed on End User's Machine ? No need to install the vb to run the exe by the way.

Comment: Thanks Mahadev but I already did what you told me to do and it still is not working. What I do is I install the visual studio into the client's machine, Open the database in VS Server Explorer. If I can open it from there, then the program can run. I just delete everything, except for the database and the debug folder then uninstall the VS program. I found one solution, though it's not really a solution, I just created an access local database.